# Как правильно записать оператор go to

Tags: c++

```
start1:
cout<<" Введите  D        = " << endl;
if ((D<0.65)&&( D>0.65))
go to start1;
cin>> D;
```

error: 'go' не был объявлен в этой области

Comment: Наверное, потому что должно быть goto. А вообще, goto - плохая практика

Comment: Спасибо поправил

Comment: goto, как и любой другой инструмент, может быть как хорошим, так и поганим. И если Дейкстра не осилил его, то это же не значит, что он плох.

Comment: нееееет только не goto умоляю прекрати

Comment: в ассемблере - небходимый а в плюсах шлак безполезный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не очень сложно!

Надо сначала убрать пробел между `go` и `to`, три раза ударить в бубен и попробовать скомпилировать еще раз...

Результат вас удивит :)

Comment: Спасибо поправил

Answer (score 3):

Если сильно хочется через библиотеку, то и это  можно. Создайте h файл и вставьте такое

```
#define go goto
#define to
```

(эти строки можно и после #include добавить).

Все, теперь код будет работать.

Comment: Только главное потом не создавать переменные с именами `go` и `to` :)